# Using pymssql to connect to SQL Server in Windows

Tags: sql-server, pymssql

- Pymssql -V:2.2.1
- Python -V: 3.8
- DB: SQL Server 2008 R2

This is my code：

```py
class read_sql(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # 服务器名
        self.server = HOST_24
        # 用户名
        self.user = SQL_SERVER_USER
        # 密码
        self.password = SQL_SERVER_PASSWORD
        # 数据库名
        self.database = PUBMED_DB
        # 连接数据库
        try:
            self.conn = pymssql.connect(self.server, self.user, self.password, self.database)
            # 创建cursor缓冲区,用来存放sql语句
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise ValueError('数据库链接实例化出错')

    def query(self, query_str):
        # 输入query_str查询语句,内容返回到cursor缓冲区内
        self.cursor.execute(query_str)
        # 接收全部的返回结果行.
        row = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return row


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sql_data = read_sql()
    row = sql_data.query("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM JinMo_CheckTable  order by id desc")
    print(row)
```

This is my first time connecting to SQL Server!

I get this error:

> pymssql._mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (18456, b"\xe7\x94\xa8\xe6\x88\xb7 'sa' \xe7\x99\xbb\xe5\xbd\x95\xe5\xa4\xb1\xe8\xb4\xa5\xe3\x80\x82DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:
>
> General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server
>
> DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:
> Adaptive Server connection failed (192.168.0.24)
>
> DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:
> Adaptive Server connection failed (192.168.0.24)

Please give me some suggestions - thanks !

Comment: 2008 R2? Probably you need to downgrade the TDS protocol version of your driver to 7.3 or less because SQL Server 2008 R2 is old and unsupported.

Comment: emm!!!! Maybe not. Because the same codes can successfully connect localdbserver.

Comment: i solve this error,i set a wrong db_name to connecting... stupid me ....23333